# Additive combinatorics in Hamming weights of addition of numbers modulo $2^n$ with prescribed Hamming weight

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, computer-science, harmonic-analysis, additive-combinatorics

I wonder if anyone could point me to a reference about the following type of combinatorics problem:

Fix $n $. For an integer $k \in [n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, let $A(k)$ be the set of integers in $[0, 2^n-1]$ that have Hamming weight $k$ in their binary representation. Fix $w \in [n]$ and let $m_1 < \cdots < m_k \in [n] \setminus \{w\}$ be distinct integers.

**Question:** What is the number of integers $x \in A(w)$ that belong to $A(m_1) + \cdots + A(m_k)$, where addition is taken modulo $2^n$. That is, how many integers in $[0, 2^n-1]$ of Hamming weight $w$ can be written as the sum of $k$ integers of Hamming weight $m_1, \ldots, m_k$, respectively, where addition is the regular addition modulo $2^n$ (commonly used by computers).

Seems like a convoluted not that easy problem because of carry of digits in addition. Nevertheless I have a feeling one should be able to count and have a formula. References or comments are very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I am not quite understanding the question, but is this just asking for the size of the span of $\cup A(m_i)$? In which case it seems you could get all of the numbers in the desired range by having a single $m_i$. For instance, if $m_1=1$ then you get the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ which spans the set.

Comment: I think there is some confusion, maybe the way I wrote it. I don't mean union of sets, but the addition of the sets (this the set containing the addition of all the elements in those sets). Also I mean regular addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ modulo $2^n$, i.e., the regular addition operation of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$. Not the XOR of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^n$. Thus these sets are not vector spaces under this (regular) addition. The problem is then harder than in the analogous case of dyadic groups because of carry when you add.